# Virtualbox ubuntu 1204 guest - guest additions installed, but graphics driver unknown

Tags: 12.04, graphics, virtualbox

I have an ubuntu 12.04 LTS guest in VBOX inside my native Windows 7. The graphics suddenly "stop drawing" or something, it stops updating the screen. I have tried adjusting the video memory (from 128mb to 64 mb and back), adjusting the RAM (it has 2048mb, before it was 1024mb) and tried running on the alternate chipset ICH9.

I noticed that inside Ubuntu, in the system settings->details, it says that the graphics driver is unknown, and the experience is standard. The guest additions are installed, but still. Is this normal?

Alternatively, what else can be wrong if this is not the issue?

UPDATE: I have now disabled the 3d acceleration. If someone knows how to solve this, please provide an answer, I will be super happy.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

Comment: After doing this driver is set to Chromium. Better, but it still doesn't draw the screen for instance on drag and drop of cards in Trello using Google Chrome. I just give up on 3d I think...

Comment: that was just to solve unknown graphics.. have u installed box guest editition?

Comment: yes the guest additions are installed.

Comment: See if 1) an update your guest Ubuntu (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or via Update Manager - you may have to reinstall the guest additions after that), and 2) an update of the drivers for your host (Windows) graphics card solves your issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 12.04 guest working flawlessly both on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 hosts. We can compare both mine and yours and see what's different.

What is your version of VirtualBox? Is it the OSE or Oracle's Proprietary version?

Also, VirtualBox uses some portions of your real hardware. What's yours?

Comment: VBOX v 4.2.10. I read that I could use my 3d Graphics card directly but I have not done that as that is experimental. It has 2048 MB ram and the full 128MB of graphics memory. I had 2 processors, I try now to reduce it to 1 and turn off IO APIC. Seems to be very slow now, so I don't think this is the fix.

Comment: I have PAE/NX turned on

Comment: ￼Runtime Attributes
Screen Resolution
1600x774x32￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼
Clipboard Mode
Bidirectional￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Drag'n'Drop Mode
Bidirectional￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼
VT-x/AMD-V
Enabled￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼
Nested Paging
Enabled￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Guest Additions
4.2.10 r84104￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼
Guest OS Type
Linux 2.6 (64 bit)
Remote Desktop Server Port
Not Available￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No I am running it without 3d.